# Multi-line search and replace

Tags: python, linux, unix, awk, sed

I have an unstructured file and I would like to search and replace pattern of strings.

- Must replace the string that exists between SELECT and FROM strings; the one's outside of this pattern should stay as is.

File format is like

```
col4 is required to be upper so
make col4 upper
abc 12345 !$% DATA SELECT 
col1 as col1,
col2 as col2.
col3,
sch.col4 as col4,
sch.tab.col4 as col4_1,
col4,
col5 FROM sch.tab
xyz 34354 ^&* DATA SELECT
col5 as col5,
col3,
col4,
col4 as col4,
col4 FROM
blah blah blah
```

I want to replace:

- `col4,` with `upper(col4) as col4,`
- `sch.col4` with `upper(sch.col4)`
- `sch.tab.col4` with `upper(sch.tab.col4)`
- `col4`(if col4 is at the end of select query) with `upper(col4) as col4`

The file is on linux server and I tried using sed and awk to narrow down the lines containing col4 but could not move forward from there.

I was able to identify one pattern using below

```
awk '/SELECT/,/FROM/' test_file.txt | awk '/col4/{print $0, NR}' | awk -F AS '{print $1}'
```

Find the text between SELECT and FROM
Identify the lines that have col4
print the first field

```
sed -n -e '/SELECT/,/FROM/p' -e 's/\(\([a-zA-Z]\{1,\}\.\)\{0,\}\)col4/upper(\0)/g' test_file.txt
```

and using sed

Actual:

```
col4 is required to be upper so
make col4 upper
abc 12345 !$% DATA SELECT
col1 as col1,
col2 as col2.
col3,
sch.col4 as col4,
sch.tab.col4 as col4_1,
col4,
col5 FROM sch.tab
xyz 34354 ^&* DATA SELECT
col5 as col5,
col3,
col4,
col4 as col4,
col4 FROM
blah blah blah
```

Expected result:

```
col4 is required to be upper so
make col4 upper
abc 12345 !$% DATA SELECT
col1 as col1,
col2 as col2.
col3,
upper(sch.col4) as col4,
upper(sch.tab.col4) as col4_1,
upper(col4) as col4,
col5 FROM sch.tab
xyz 34354 ^& DATA SELECT
col5 as col5,
col3,
upper(col4) as col4,
upper(col4) as col4,
upper(col4) as col4 FROM
blah blah blah
```

Any help is much appreciated!!

Comment: Python also works for you?

Comment: @Juan C Hi, Yes, Python 3 works too.

Comment: @oguzismail Apologies. This is my first post, Edited now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With sed:

```
sed '/SELECT/,/FROM/ {s/as col4 *//;s/\([A-Za-z]*\.\)\{0,\}col4/upper(&) as col4/;}' file
```

**Explanations:**

- `s/as col4 *//`: existing `as col4` is removed to prevent duplicates after second substitution
- `\([A-Za-z]*\.\)\{0,\}col4`: search for 0 or more combinations of letters and dots followed by `col4`
- `upper(&) as col4/;`: replace with new text(matching string is inserted using `&`)

Comment: Thank you @SLePort. This solution worked great for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think this, at least, 95% does it. Please tell me if there's an error:

```
with open('ej.txt', 'r') as file:
    string=file.read().replace('\n',' ')


import re

matches=re.findall(r'SELECT.*?FROM',string)
replacements={"col4,":"upper(col4) as col4,",
             "sch.col4":"upper(sch.col4)",
             "sch.tab.col4":"upper(sch.tab.col4)",
             "col4 as col4,": "upper(col4) as col4,"}
new_matches=[]
for match in matches:
    for k,v in replacements.items():
        match=match.replace(k,v)
    new_matches.append(match)


for k,v in {k:v for k,v in zip(matches,new_matches)}.items() :
    string=string.replace(k,v)

string
```

Comment: Thank you Juan! I will try with this code and feedback with results.

Comment: It worked for the most part but since the file was read as one string - I find it hard to put it back in its original format. Is there a way to keep the format as is and update in place? Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short awk script performing your request:

```
awk '/SELECT/,/FROM/ {$0=gensub(/^[^[:space:]]*col4/,"upper(\\0)",-1);}1' input.txt
```

#### The output is:

```
abc 12345 !$% DATA SELECT
col1 as col1,
col2 as col2.
col3,
upper(sch.col4) as col4,
upper(sch.tab.col4) as col4_1,
upper(col4),
col5 FROM sch.tab
xyz 34354 ^&* DATA SELECT
col5 as col5,
col3,
upper(col4),
upper(col4) as col4,
upper(col4) FROM
blah blah blah
```

#### Explanation:

`/SELECT/,/FROM/` inclusive range selecting each line from /SELECT/ to /FROM/

`$0=gensub(***)` update current line with substitions from gensub()

`/^[^[:space:]]*col4/` search for non space prefix to col4 at the beginning of line

`upper(\\0)",-1` replace found-match with-upper('found-match') only first match

`1` print the current line.
1

Comment: Thank you! This does part of it but 
I want to replace "col4," with "upper(col4) as col4,"
                  "sch.col4" with "upper(sch.col4)"
                  "sch.tab.col4" with "upper(sch.tab.col4)"
                  "col4"(if col4 is at the end of select query) with upper(col4) as col4

Answer (score 0):

Your description of the transformations you need is incomplete (e.g. you say you want to change `col4,` to `upper(col4) as col4,` but line 7 of the expected output doesn't reflect that) so I set that aside and just wrote this which but will produce the output you want from the input you provided (using GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match()) and hopefully this is what you actually want:

```
$ cat tst.awk
/SELECT/ { inBlock=1 }
inBlock {
    if ( match($0,/^((sch\.(tab\.)?)?col4\>)( as .*)/,a) ) {
        $0 = "upper(" a[1] ")" a[4]
    }
    else if ( match($0,/^(col4\>)(.*)/,a) ) {
        $0 = "upper(" a[1] ") as " a[1] a[2]
    }
}
/FROM/   { inBlock=0 }
{ print }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
col4 is required to be upper so
make col4 upper
abc 12345 !$% DATA SELECT
col1 as col1,
col2 as col2.
col3,
upper(sch.col4) as col4,
upper(sch.tab.col4) as col4_1,
upper(col4) as col4,
col5 FROM sch.tab
xyz 34354 ^&* DATA SELECT
col5 as col5,
col3,
upper(col4) as col4,
upper(col4) as col4,
upper(col4) as col4 FROM
blah blah blah
```

Comment: Thanks Ed! This solution helped me.