# Special characters in character class

Tags: sql, regex, linux, unix, sed

I would like to match below patterns and replace them with sql keywords around them.

The files are on Linux server with SQL code in them. I tried to match with some regular expressions. Ideally, I would like to match Any number of special characters, alphabets and ignore case for col_4 to find first strings that contain col4 in the query.

I tried working with below expression and also with the help of community's response from another question.

```
[A-Za-z_#]*\.\)\{0,\}col4
```

#### Source text:

```
SELECT 
col1 as col1,
[&"tab.sch"].tabl_nm.col2 as col2,
col3,
[&"tab.sch"].tabl_nm.col_4 as col_4, 
\#tab.sch#.tab_nm.COL_4 col_4,
col5
FROM yada yada
```

I want to be able to wrap upper around first instance of col_4 fields ignoring case

#### Expected result

```
SELECT 
col1 as col1,
[&"tab.sch"].tabl_nm.col2 as col2,
col3,
upper([&"tab.sch"].tabl_nm.col_4) as col_4,
upper(#tab.sch#.tab_nm.COL_4) col_4,
col5
FROM yada yada
```

Comment: You don't need to be so specific about what you are matching: I would use a regular expression like "one or more **_non-whitespace_ characters**
 followed by 'col_4'" -- is that enough to get you started?

Comment: Do exactly the same thing I showed you in [my answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56194957/1745001) but with just a tweaked regexp to match your new target strings.

Comment: Do you really have two `col_4` lines?

Comment: @EdMorton I am working on that.

Comment: @WalterA I made that up.. but that is one of the scenarios. I want to be able to match both the patterns. thanks.

Comment: @Emma - I'm sorry but your edit wasn't an improvement - it defaced the post by leading to the display of a `\\` in the antepenultimate source line. You have to be careful when changing the formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the feedback. I was able to solve this with below code

```
sed '/SELECT/,/FROM/ {s/[Aa][Ss] [Cc][oO][lL]_4 *//;s/\([[:punct:]A-Za-z0-9]*\.\)\{0,\}[Cc][oO][lL]_4 /SUBSTR(&,1,30) as col4/;}'
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to change two strings, look what they have in common. When they have nothing in common (or to complex), first change one and than the other:

```
sed 's/a/b/; s/c/d/' inputfile
```

Can you keep it simple by only looking at the last part?

```
sed -r 's/^([^ ]*[.]col_4) /upper(\1)/i' source.txt
```